# Any way to embed spreadsheet into android app?

Tags: android, embed, spreadsheet, google-docs

I'm new to android development and my first project requires a way to somehow embed a spreadsheet from Google docs into my application. Is there any way to do so? I was unable to find any API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure how experienced you are at programming but what I would recommend is exporting your spread sheet as a .csv file. From there load the csv file into memory loop through it and build a object that can hold each column of your spreadsheet. After that build an ArrayList and loop through the .csv file populating each row into the object. After that use this tutorial http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html to build a custom listview that will display each row as a list item(or each row from a the spread sheet).

Answer (score 0):

Only way to embed it is using WebView.
Google sites has an inbuilt gadget for Spreadsheets.

So you create a Google sites page with a single spreadsheet gadget and then load that URL in the webview --- ugly but works